# Why is returning a Springboot ResponseEntitty so slow?

Tags: performance, spring-boot, kotlin

So I am building this springboot REST consumer within an API. The API request is dependend on a different API.

The user can make a Request to my API and my API makes a request to another service to log the user in.

While building this I came to the conclusion that returning a ResponseEntity is much slower than just returning the result in the body of the request.

This my fast code, response time less than a seccond:

```
@PostMapping("/adminLogin")
fun adminLogin(@RequestBody credentials: Credentials): AuthResponse {
    return RestTemplate().getForEntity(
            "$authenticatorURL/adminLogin?userName=${credentials.username}&passWord=${credentials.password}",
            AuthResponse::class.java).body
}
```

When doing this it takes lots of seconds to respond:

```
@PostMapping("/adminLogin")
fun adminLogin(@RequestBody credentials: Credentials): ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> {
    return RestTemplate().getForEntity(
            "$authenticatorURL/adminLogin?userName=${credentials.username}&passWord=${credentials.password}",
            AuthResponse::class.java)
}
```

Can someone explain to me what the difference is why one approach is faster than the other.

Comment: How do you know it's the return type of your functions have such an impact for a performance? Maybe it's the third party service calls?

Comment: That is what I thought, the service is running locally on my machine. When making the call in postman directly to the service it is very fast. I have know idea how removing the Response type can affect the performance.

Comment: It is not really a problem, but rather something I noticed. Both examples work fine, only one is faster.

Comment: I think, in the end `AuthResponse` object is still wrapped in `ResponseEntity` underneath, but that's my guess. Anyway I'll conduct some tests for my curiousity.

Comment: Take a look: https://pastebin.com/5pE9Dbrs . I created simple rest api, and a controller. Two methods, one returning `String` one returning `ResponseEntity<String>`. Not those are nanos, so the differences are minimal.

Comment: the difference is very small, but the interesting part is that still by adding code you can make it faster. I would expect the opposite. Because with only returning `String`  you have to access the body of the ResponsEntity and I would expecr it that it would do the same operation

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I suppose, that when you do not add the `ResponseEntity<type>` it is going to be added by Spring anyways since you don't only get the object, still you get response status, headers etc, etc.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable explanation, that spring does do some stuff for you under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. The problem was as follows: imagine the API I use is sending a json like this:

```
{"id": "12"}
```

what I do is take that into a ResponseEntity, and IdDTO stores the id field as an integer. When I returned this ResponseEntity as a response to my request, it returns this:

```
{"id": 12}// notice the absence of string quotes around 12
```

The problem is as follows: the API that I used sends the Content-Length header to be equal to 12, but after my DTO conversion it becomes 10.
Spring does not recalculate the content length and the client is reading the 10 characters you sent, then waiting for other 2. It never receives anything and Spring closes the connection after 1 minute(that is the default timeout for a connection).

If you create a new response entity and put your data into it, Spring will calculate the new content length and it will be as fast as the first case you mentioned.